# How to do FB feed share post without leaving my hybrid app?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, facebook-javascript-sdk, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making mobile app using Sencha touch which will be bundled as native app and installed on devices. In my app on certain pages I want to add "share" functionality which is supposed to post some data to user's feed. While testing on browser I can to do that by opening a window with FB sharing url like "https://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed" or "https://m.facebook.com/sharer.php" and passing all related params as explained in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

But when this app is bundled and I share with this, user is moved to browser and cannot return to app because `redirect_uri` cannot point to app which is why I wanted to open this dialog within my app, probably in an iFrame. This is also not possible because these dialogs are not allowed to be embedded in iframe by META tags and in order to surpass it I have to do user login which again is another dialog which I cannot open in my app's iFrame.

I also looked at sample sencha app http://blooming-day-7830.herokuapp.com/ but it also takes user to separate login page instead of opening in-app dialog.

So my questions is **how does hybrid apps connect with FB without moving out user to browser**?

Comment: you could use https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin considering you already using phonegap for packaging. I've used it and it's exactly what you want.

Comment: I wasn't planning to use phonegap because Sencha now provides native packaging and also I don't need any device interaction in my app like camera, contacts or accelerometer BUT now you are saying seamless FB login is not possible without phonegap so I have to reconsider my decision. Its hard to believe that phonegap is only way out

Comment: @phobos Do you know of any similar plugin for Twitter?

Comment: i don't know if phonegap is *only way* or not. I used it because I had requirement of using GCM and other service stuff. So I used phonegap just as wrapper. Don't know about twitter though. But i guess there might be something already avaiable. It's so common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you decide to use PhoneGap you can try the following two options. You will have to check for the iOS version before you switch your Phonegap call to. . .

**Option 1 :** for iOS before 6.0

Phonegap has a pretty nifty ChildBrowser plugin that you can use to load the FB share page without leaving the app for iOS 5.0 and below.

**Option 2 :** for iOS 6.0+

Facebook Share functionality has now been added to iOS. So all you have to do, is call a custom plugin class that you create, and call the standard FB share code using a basic Phonegap plugin call. You won't leave the app, the ChildBrowser doesn't have to show up, instead, you'll get the stock iOS-FB share sheet that will show up, you can add pictures, text, and so on, and post to facebook.

Comment: Thanks @SashaZd I will try this. Can you show me some sample code or example of how to do this? Sorry, I am new to Phonegap please help.